# design pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

In [You don't know JS type & grammar](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch1.md), a design pattern called "dependency injection" is shown in the end of the chapter 1, which I know is not point of this chapter, but I was confused by the example.

the example code is here:

```js
function doSomethingCool(FeatureXYZ) {
    var helper = FeatureXYZ ||
        function() { /*.. default feature ..*/ };

    var val = helper();
    // ..
}
```

So I want to use this function.

Because I don't know whether the FeatureXYZ exists, I dont know how to use it.
doSomethingCool() will not use the FeatureXYZ and doSomethingCool(FeatureXYZ) will throw error if no FeatureXYZ exists. Thus, the function may be a meaningless function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default parameters to set a default function to call if no parameter is passed, or use the parameter instead if passed to the function.

Use bracket notation to reference the property `"FeatureXYZ"` at either `window` object or the object which `"FeatureXYZ"` is expected to be a property. Bracket notation should not throw an error if the property is not defined at the object.

```js
function FeatureXYZ () {
  return {def:456}
}

function doSomethingCool(FeatureXYZ = window["FeatureXYZ"] /* obj["FeatureXYZ"] */) {
  var helper = FeatureXYZ || function config() { 
  /*.. default feature ..*/ 
    return {abc:123}
  };
  var val = helper();
  // ..
  return val
}

console.log(doSomethingCool());
```

Comment: maybe a solution, but in my case whether dosomethingcool uses default feather or featherxyz should totally depend on the outer side environment, not the way function was call.As we don't know the functionality of featherxyz, we are not able to use default parameter way.(suppose we load may files in our project and don't even know whether featurexyz exits)

Comment: What is expected result if `FeatureXYZ` does not exist? Should there be a default function called, or no function called? That is, what is the logic which you are implementing as to existence or non-existence of `FeatureXYZ`?

Comment: a default function called which is written inside the dosomethingcool function. only featherxyz existed in the outer side of dosomething function will the default function be dropped away.

Comment: Not sure what issue is? If `FeatureXYZ` is defined, is the variable defined globally?

Comment: the logic is when i write this function i don't know whether other has already write the function i need, so i check for that. if other already write that function, i use his/hers. otherwise, use my function.

Comment: the difficult part is that i don't know whether it is defined or not. the link i provide in my question has other solutions to this using typeof.

Comment: @teek See updated post. If `FeatureXYZ` is defined globally, you can use bracket notation `window["FeatureXYZ"]`, else use `obj["FeatureXYZ"]`, where `obj` is the object where `FeatureXYZ` is expected to be a property.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `||` operator returns the first value if it's not null or undefined. If it is, it returns the second value. Example:

```
var x = null;
var y = x || 5;
```

`x` is null, hence `z` will be set equal to `5`. If `x` would be, for example, `4`, `y` would be set to `4` as well.

JavaScript has the feature (or oddity, depends on the viewer), that you do not have to pass every parameter a function has. For example, if you have the following function:

```
function(x, y) {
    return x * (y || 5);
}
```

It would not result in an error if you call the function without passing `y`, because it would multiply `x` by `5` if `y` is not provided (and therefore undefined).

This is how the example works: It sets `helper` equal to `FeatureXYZ`, or, if it is not passed as an argument, e.g. `doSomethingCool()` (and therefore undefined), it is set to a default function. That way later in the code, when you execute `helper()`, you either use the passed function, or the default one, if it's not given.